# Playing wav files in the Android browser

Tags: android, android-browser

Using the html 5 audio tag it appears it is possible to play back an mp3 through the android browser. Is it possible to do it using a wav file? If not through the audio tag is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 `<audio>` tag supports WAV files. Depending on your version of Android, though, it might not work in the native browser. For example, [no format worked in Android 2.2.](http://www.brianhadaway.com/html5-audio-support-on-android-devices/) I tried it on my own phone, the Galaxy Nexus with Jelly Bean using the excellent test on [Are We Playing Yet?](http://www.areweplayingyet.org), and found that [it was not supported.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJbvr.png)

The other way to do it is to transcode your WAV file to a different format and use HTML5 audio. The Flash based [WavPlayer](https://github.com/francois2metz/WavPlayer) might work too, but please remember that Flash was discontinued for Android and is not guaranteed to be installed on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

android version 2.2's native browser supports ".wav" file. but android 4.0's native browser does not support ".wav" file.

Comment: Not true I tried on the HTC sensation Ice Cream Sandwich and it worked fine. I think it might be your brands browser.

Comment: i am using Galaxy s2. we can't open .wav file in itz native browser. I think the native browser is not supporting HTML5. it might be device browser issue, because when i opened the same page with chrome browser, it worked with out any issue.